# java, when (and for how long) can a thread cache the value of a non-volatile variable?

Tags: java, concurrency

From this post: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_typical_use.shtml

> ```
> public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
>   private volatile boolean pleaseStop;
>
>   public void run() {
>     while (!pleaseStop) {
>       // do some stuff...
>     }
>   }
>
>   public void tellMeToStop() {
>     pleaseStop = true;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If the variable were not declared volatile (and without other
>   synchronization), then it would be legal for the thread running the
>   loop to cache the value of the variable at the start of the loop and
>   never read it again.

In Java 5 or later:

is the last paragraph correct?

So, exactly at what moment can a thread cache the value of the `pleaseStop` variable (and for how long)? just before calling one of StoppableTask's functions (`run`, `tellMeTpStop`) of the object? (and the thread must update the variable when exiting the function at the latest?)

can you point me to a documentation/tutorial reference about this (Java 5 or later)?

---

**Update: here it is my compilation of answers posted on this question:**

Without using `volatile` nor `synchronized`, there are actually two problems with the above program:

1- Threads can cache the variable `pleaseStop` since the very first moment that the thread starts and don't update it never again. so, the loop would keep going forever. this can be solved by either using `volatile` or `synchronized`. This thread cache mechanism does *not* exist in C.

2- The java compiler can optimise the code, and replace `while(!pleaseStop) {...}` to `if (!pleaseStop) { while (true) {...}}`. so, the loop would keep going forever. again, this can be solved by either using `volatile` or `synchronized`. This compiler optimisation exists also in C.

Some more info:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things15/

Comment: forever ..... or as long as it can

Comment: One practical truth in what the tutorial is referring to has more to do with what HotSpot is allowed to do. Hotspot can turn `while (!pleaseStop)` in to `while (true)` if `pleaseStop` is not `volatile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### When can it cache?

As for your question about "when can it cache" the value, the answer to that is "always". To understand what that means, read on. Processors have storage called caches, which make it possible for the running thread to access values in memory by reading from the cache rather than from memory. The running thread can also write to this cache as if it were writing the value to memory. Thus, so long as the thread is running, it could be using the cache to store the data it's using. Something has to explicitly happen to flush the value from the cache to memory. For a single-threaded process, this is all well and dandy, but if you have another thread, it might be trying to read the data from memory while the other thread is plugging away reading and writing it to the processor cache without flushing to memory.

### How long can it cache?

As for the "for how long" part- the answer is unfortunately forever unless you do something about it. Synchronizing on the data in question is one way to force a flush from the cache so that all threads see the updates to the value. For more detail about ways to cause a flush, see the next section.

### Where's some Documentation?

As for the "where's the documentation" question, a good place to start is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html). For specifically how you can force a flush, java refers to this by discussing whether one action (such as a data write) appears to "happen before" another (like a data read). For more about this, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).

### What about `volatile`?

`volatile` in essence prevents the type of processor caching described above. This ensures that all writes to a variable are visible from other threads. To learn more, the tutorial you linked to in your post seems like a good start.

Comment: Nice but in practice, a machine is always doing something, running an OS, even if your program is idle, OS will eventually want to use that CPU core and put some stuff into registers, and as far as i understand that means pending writes are going to be flushed from buffer to main memory... I might be wrong though :) Please let me know if that's the case... 
My point is you will never have that case when you wrote something and it stayed there forever...

Comment: i don't know how long it takes for non volatile write to be flushed but that's something that can be measured, and will probably heavily depend on how big your caches are and how busy your cores are...

Comment: I actually don't know about the "in practice," only the "in theory." In the sense that the spec makes no formal guarantees about timing of flushes to main memory if you're not using volatile. But I would imagine you're right that probably most implementations will flush eventually under normal circumstances, and it may not even take that long in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant documentation is on the volatile keyword (Java Language Specification, Chapter 8.3.1.4) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) and the Java memory model (Java Language Specification, Chapter 17.4) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Declaring the parameter volatile ensures that there is some synchronization of actions by other threads that might change its value. Without  declaring  volatile, Java can reorder operations taken on a parameter by different threads.

As the Spec says (see 8.3.1.4), for parameters declared  volatile,"accesses ... occur exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear to occur during execution of the program text by each thread..."

So the caching you speak of can happen anytime if the parameter is not  volatile. But there is enforcement of consistent access to that parameter by the Java memory model if the parameter is declared volatile. But no such enforcement would take place if not (unless the threads are synchronized).

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is in section 17 of the Java Language Specification, especially [17.4 Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

The correct viewpoint is to start by assuming multi-threaded code won't work, and try to force it to work whether it likes it or not. Without the `volatile` declaration, or similar, there would be nothing forcing the read of `pleaseStop` to ever see the write if it happens in another thread.

I agree with the Java Concurrency in Practice recommendation. It is a good distillation of the implications of the JLS material for practical Java programming.